# Creating a key-value pair in one foreach iteration, and reassigning the value in another

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

**Background**

I'm trying to figure out the actual playing time of a footballer (soccer player) in a given match. In other words, the time during which he was on the field as an active player.

Some user-inputted data is provided:

- if and when the player was substituted, and whether he was subbed on or off
- whether the player started the match on the pitch or on the bench
- the start and end timestamps for each half of the match

**Problem**

I'm trying to create pairs of events, which represent a 'unit' of actual playing time. In this example, in the first iteration of the the outermost foreach, I create an array:

`$aptPeriods = array(
          'start' => 32,
          'end' => ''
    )`

In the second iteration, the script identifies the empty 'end' value, and tries to reassign it.

```
$playerSubstitutions = array(
    array(
        'type' => 'on',
        'time' => '38'
    ),
    array(
        'type' => 'off',
        'time' => '68'
    )
);

foreach($playerSubstitutions as $sub) {
    // If the sub type is 'on', create a new aptPeriod and set the 'end' time to nothing
    if($sub['type'] == 'on') {
        $subOnEvent = array(
            'start' => $sub['time'],
            'end' => ''
        );
        array_push($aptPeriods, $subOnEvent);
    // If the sub type is 'off', scan the aptPeriods array for an empty 'end' value, then set it to the subOff time
    } elseif($sub['type'] == 'off') {
        foreach($aptPeriods as $period) {
            if($period['end'] == '') {
                $period['end'] == $sub['time'];
            }
        } 
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($aptPeriods); echo '</pre>';
```

This returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 38
            [end] => 
        )

)
```

The innermost foreach is definitely executing, and `$sub['time']` is definitely set, but the blank 'end' value is not being reassigned. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This code seems rather unrefined.  Can you explain what it is actually mean to do?  And provide a couple other different input arrays?  There has got to be a more efficient/clean way to do this.

Comment: Good point. Please see the edited question.

Comment: What does the input array look like if the players isn't a "starting" player (sitting out to start the match)?  What if the player starts on the field?  If I can see how the data is structured, I can suggest refinements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the original values then use...

```
     foreach($aptPeriods as &$period) {
            if($period['end'] == '') {
                $period['end'] = $sub['time'];
            }
        } 
    unset ($period);
```

(Note the & in the $period bit)

The foreach was making a copy of each array element and you were modifying that and not the original array.

Also - as pointed out, the == in the assignment is actually testing for equals, so this should just be a single =.

Answer (score 0):

No messy referenced variables.  I've generated my own hypothetical input array for testing.

Code:

```
$playerSubstitutions=[
    ['type'=>'on','time'=>'5'],
    ['type'=>'off','time'=>'25'],
    ['type'=>'on','time'=>'38'],
    ['type'=>'off','time'=>'41'],
    ['type'=>'on','time'=>'58']];
$matchDuration='90';

foreach(array_chunk($playerSubstitutions,2) as $set){  // process subbing in pairs
    $aptPeriods[]=[
        'start'=>$set[0]['time'],
        'end'=>(isset($set[1]['time'])?$set[1]['time']:$matchDuration)
    ];
}
var_export($aptPeriods);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'start' => '5',
    'end' => '25',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'start' => '38',
    'end' => '41',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'start' => '58',
    'end' => '90',
  ),
)
```

Code #2:

```
$tally=0;
foreach($playerSubstitutions as $sub){
    if($sub['type']=='on'){
        $tally-=$sub['time'];
    }else{
        $tally+=$sub['time'];
    }
}
if($sub['type']!='off'){$tally+=$matchDuration;}  // if player finished the match on the field
echo $tally;
// output: 55
```